# Multiple simple controllers inside a thread group in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have two loop controllers inside a simple controller.
But it stops running after the execution of first loop even if the results is successful.

Structure is given below

**ThreadGroup**

- Simple Controller 1

  - HTTP Request
  - Loop Controller1 (Loops 10 times with a CSV file)
  - Loop Controller2 (Loops 25 times with another CSV file)
- Simple Controller 2

  - HTTP Request 1
  - HTTP Request 2
  - HTTP Request 3
  - Loop Controller 3 (Loops 15 times 3rd CSV file)

But execution stops after completing Loop controller 2.  It doesn't go for the Loop controller 2 or doesn't start Simple Controller 2.  If Simple Controller 1 is disabled, it will run Simple Controller 2 successfully.

Any suggestion will be of great help.
Thanks

Comment: Your questions doesn't provide enough information to help. How did you define the loop controller and how did you use your CSV? Did you use the "CSV Data Set Config"? And if so: how did you configure it? BTW: the simple controller is not really a 'controller', only a container to organize your script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that, your [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) is configured with `Stop thread of EOF` set to true.

> Stop thread on EOF? Should the thread be stopped on EOF

If not, you probably have another element with stop action you didn't mention as Runtime Controller or Test Action.